# Function template with return type T doesn't compile

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, function-templates

The following code compiles fine:

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T &item) { return; }

int main() 
{
  f("const string literal");
}
```

Compilation succeeded at ideone : http://ideone.com/dR6iZ

But when I mention the return type, it doesn't compile:

```
template<typename T>
T f(const T &item) { return item; }

int main() 
{
  f("const string literal");
}
```

Now it gives error:

> prog.cpp:6: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(const char [21])’

Code at ideone : http://ideone.com/b9aSb

Even if I make the return type `const T`, it [doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/Bt3mF).

My question is :

- Why does it not compile?
- What does the return type has to do with the error and the function template instantiation?

Comment: A good compiler (with warning enabled) should warn you that the top-level `const` in an argument or return type is ignored, as far as I know. Therefore returning `T` or `T const` does not change anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot return an array from a function, so template instantiation fails, and there's no matching function.

You get this particular error because of [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) - It's not really an error that the compiler cannot instantiate your function, it *is* an error that there's no matching function.

You *can* return a reference to an array - returning `T const &` will work.

EDIT: In response to comments:

First, this is actually a decent example of SFINAE.

```
template<typename T> T f(const T &item) { return item; }
char const * f(void const * item) { return 0; }
int main() {
  f("abc");
}
```

When the compiler compiles this, it'll first try to instantiate the templated f, to create an *exact match* for the type `const char [3]`. This fails, because of the mentioned reasons. It'll then select the inexact match, the plain function, and in the call decay the `const char [3]` to a `const char *`.

Comment: @Erik: can't compiler instantiate `const char *` as well?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit? How would that code try to return an array?

Comment: @Nawaz: No, your literal *is* a `const char[21]` so that's the type that's used.

Comment: @Erik: I was expecting `const char[21]` to decay to `const char*`. why does it not decay?

Comment: @Erik: I see. Had the same misconception as Nawaz, thanks for making that explicit.

Comment: @Nawaz: It would decay to match a function call, but won't for parameter substitution

Comment: @Erik: Can you please elaborate more on the last comment?

Comment: @Nawaz: There's no rule allowing decay of array to pointer for template parameter substitution. Arrays and pointers are distinct types, and there's an explicit rule allowing decay in certain situations, template parameters are not one of these.

Comment: @Nawaz: For the same reason you wouldn't expect: `struct foo { operator int() { return 0; } }; f(foo());` to deduce `T` to `int`.

Comment: @Erik: I liked the edit in your post. But you know, I was experimenting something very similar, it's from there I started to have this doubt which ultimately made me to create this topic.

Comment: @Erik: BTW, are you sure when you said *"it'll first try to instantiate the templated f, to create an exact match for the type const char [3]"*?

Comment: @Nawaz: Actually, no - I don't remember what order it'll use there. I'll check and edit.

Comment: @Erik: Why did you changed `char const*` to `void const*`? I think, it's less interesting, and doesn't really help me understanding the behaviour. After all, `const string literal` could be either `char const*` or `char const [21]`. I mean, the choice should be between *pointer* or *array*.

Comment: @Nawaz: A string literal *is* a `const char []`, always. It decays in overload resolution and call contexts (and e.g assignment)

Comment: @Erik: That is why `void const*` doesn't help here. If the template instantiation fails, then the function which takes `const char*` should be selected. That makes me wonder: why did you change the signature of the second function in your edit, from `const char*` to `void const*`? :-/

Comment: @Nawaz: In overload resolution, `T []` and `T *` as parameters are equivalent (13.1/3) - so the compiler would select the non-template version. When a template is instantiated, there's no decay of `T[]` to `T*` - so you get an invalid function signature returning `T[]`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Return type isn't used in overload resolution - the compiler would need to select in between `(char const *)` and `(char const [N])` which are equivalent *in overload resolution context* - so it selects the non-template version. If there were no non-template version it'd select the `(char const[N])` template instantation - but not **change** `char const[N]` to `char const *` - they're equivalent in overload resolution context, but not the same type

Answer (score 0):

it looks as though you tell it that you plan on returning a T, but then you actually return a const T&. maybe try changing the declaration to:

```
template<typename T>
const T& f(const T& item) { return item; }
```

or maybe change the return value to a dereferenced version of the argument:

```
template<typename T>
T f(const T& item) { return (*item); }
```